# Error in uploading file to the server using Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to upload file to the server from android using Jersey Web Service. I have written the code but there is some problem in the code. It shows error- 
**A message body reader for Java class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and Java type class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, and MIME media type multipart/form-data was not found** 
I have added mimepull.jar to the classpath but still this error is getting generated.

This is my front end Java code-

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            CONNECTION_TIMEOUT); // Timeout
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SO_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
    FileBody fileContent= new FileBody(file);
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Global.URL);
    try {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("file", fileContent);
        httppost.setHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data");
        httppost.setEntity(entity);
        response = client.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
```

This is my web service-

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/upload_file")
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
    System.out.println("upload_file");
    String uploadedFileLocation = "/aanbieding/assets/upload/requester/"
            + fileDetail.getFileName();
    Util.saveToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);               // save uploaded file to new location
    String output = "File uploaded via Jersey based RESTFul Webservice to: "
            + uploadedFileLocation;
    System.out.println(output);
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

Please help me understanding what is wrong in this code. 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use FormDataMultipart oject in your client code to create a multipart/form data. And then add attachments to it. Make sure the attachment name and name of the parameter on the web service side are the same: Here is the sample client code wiht FormDataMultipart:

```
    FormDataMultiPart mMultiPart = null;
    byte fileContent[] = readFile(fileName); /// readfile is a method read file bytes
    if (mMultiPart == null) {
        mMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
    }
    mMultiPart.field(attachmentName, fileContent,MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveEnrollments(InputStream inputStream, String url){
    try {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);
        FormDataMultiPart fdmp = new FormDataMultiPart();
            fdmp.bodyPart(new StreamDataBodyPart("enrollments", inputStream));
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(
                "multipart/form-data").post(ClientResponse.class,
                        fdmp);
        String response= response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
        }
    catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

try this function hope this will help you.